# llamar un Fragment desde un ListFragment en android

Tags: android, android-fragment

He estado buscando por todos lados y no logro encontrar dicha respuesta, lo que pasa es que tengo un `ListFragment` y de ese `ListFragment` tengo un método `setOnItemClickListener`, todo funciona muy bien, solo que necesito llamar un `fragment` desde el `setOnItemClickListener` del `ListFragment`, por ahora solo tengo unos `TOAST` para diferenciar entre clics

**Codigo java del ListFragment**

```
public class Main2Activity extends ListFragment {

    String[] players={"uno","dos","tres"};
    int[] images={R.drawable.enrique,R.drawable.kiko,R.drawable.astiazaran};


    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    SimpleAdapter adapter;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        HashMap<String, String> map=new HashMap<String, String>();

        for(int i=0;i<players.length;i++)
        {
            map=new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("Player", players[i]);
            map.put("Image", Integer.toString(images[i]));
            data.add(map);
        }


        //KEYS IN MAP
        String[] from={"Player","Image"};
        //IDS OF VIEWS
        int[] to={R.id.nameTxt,R.id.imageView1};
        //ADAPTER
        adapter=new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), data,  R.layout.model, from, to);
        setListAdapter(adapter);


        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int pos,
                                    long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                if (pos == 0){


                   Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf("seleccionaste a 0"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

                if (pos == 1){

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf("Seleccionaste a 1"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
                if (pos == 2){

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf("seleccionaste 2"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

            }
        });



    }

    }
```

TODO FUNCIONA muy bien solo que quiero llamar a otro fragmento

**Código java del fragmento que quiero llamar en vez de poner los toast en los if del listfragment**

```
public class FragmentoInicio extends Fragment {


    public WebView mWebView;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragmento_inicio, container, false);
        mWebView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        mWebView.loadUrl("https://google.com/");

        // Enable Javascript
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        // Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a browser
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        return v;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro de tu método `onItemClick()` puedes realizar la transacción del Fragmento, suponiendo tu contenedor en el layout se llama `frame_container`:

```
  getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int pos,
                                    long id) {
            Fragmnent fragment = new FragmentoInicio();         
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            }
        });
```

---

Importante hacer notar el uso de `getSupportFragmentManager()` o `getFragmentManager()` al realizar la transacción:

Si se usan las librería de soporte (android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity) se usa :

[getSupportFragmentManager()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#getSupportFragmentManager())

de otra forma y usando una API mayor o igual a 14 se usa:

[getFragmentManager()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#getFragmentManager())

Comment: Hice lo que me mencionaste pero ahora me salio un error en esta linea.
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager(); 
me sale  Cannot resolve method 'getSupportFragmentManager()'

Comment: muchas gracias hermano, tu codigo funciono, solo la modificacion que le hice fue que en vez de getSupportFragmentManager(); lo cambie por getFragmentManager(); ...  y en la linea Fragmnent fragment = new FragmentoInicio(); Fragment estaba mal escrito ... Muchas gracias

Comment: @JorgeAlbertoAnguianoTorres si, de hecho falto precisar que si usas getSupportFragmentManager() es porque estas usando las librerías de soporte de otra forma únicamente getFragmentManager();, saludos!